# error TS1192: Module '" A.module"' has no default export

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-modules

I have created a new module 'A' and trying to import it in another module called 'B'. I am getting this error on compiling that says

> error TS1192: Module '" A.module"' has no default export

Can anyone please help on how to solve this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module has not default export after converting to Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870154/module-has-not-default-export-after-converting-to-typescript)

Answer (score 293, accepted):

This was a simple error. It occurred due to the missing `{}` around the module name in the import statement itself.

Comment: jeez. thanks... just FYI, this is whats going on lol... 

WRONG: import YourWhateverThing from './your-whatever-file.component.'
RIGHT: import {YourWhateverThing} from from './your-whatever-file.component.'

Comment: Note: This answer was added at the very initial stages of Angular 2. Please check your version and solution accordingly, since this may not work for all the similar issues as mentioned by other kind people. Cheers.

Answer (score 167):

Accepted answer didn't work for me, so I am posting more info.

I had:

```
import Module from 'module';
```

and this worked for me:

```
import * as Module from 'module';
```

src: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3337#issuecomment-107971371

Comment: jeez, lucky I found this. Thanks guys!

Comment: Thank you! To use import X from 'xPath', then there needs to be an export default.  But if there is export default, then we use import * as X from 'xPath'.  Wow!

Comment: Oh wow I feel dumb. TS was complaining about not having default exports and this was the way to go, made them all named and then imported them all so i could do ComponentName.NamedComponent

Answer (score 39):

For me this issue was addressed using `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` within `compilerOptions` in the project's tsconfig.json.

Our specific error related to a moment js import.

More about this option can be [found here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: This is the only correct option when using TypeScript to type-check plain JavaScript. If anyone else comes across this, remember to restart the language service (VS Code: Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P > TypeScript: Restart TSServer) after updating tsconfig.json if the option does not seem to come into effect immediately.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer adding the key/value to compileroptions with restart of tsserver in vscode did not help, but [`import * as foo from 'bar'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50473239/1705829) helped.

Answer (score 23):

Use:

```
import { Module } from 'module';
```

You need to insert the module name between **{...}**

Answer (score 8):

I fixed it by adding this to `tsconfig.json` in my angular project.

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

Answer (score 8):

I fixed above issue by putting the following inside the `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "esModuleInterop": true
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Weird that this answer has like the least amount of votes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing it as module, you can also require it like so:

```
const Module = require('./some_folder/module');
```

`module.ts` would then have:

```
module.exports = class Module {
    ... your module code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All above answers didn't solve my error. Below solution worked for me. Before this, I have run below command

```
npm i @types/moment-timezone --save-dev
```

And then I imported moment like below in .ts file.

```
import * as moment from "moment-timezone";
```

I hope, it will help someone. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, instead of exporting the module as named export, we need to make it a default exported module as below

```
export default class Module {
    ... your module code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Restart VSCode / IDE

I had the error showing no default export even though the file certainly did have a default export.

Quite a while later realized that sometimes VSCode gets stuck. Restarted and error resolved!