# Module has not default export after converting to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have converted the JavaScript code to Typescript and getting the error

> Module has no default export

I have tried importing using the curly braces and exporting using module.exports but none of them worked.

**contactController.ts**

```
const contacts: String[] = [];

// Handle index actions
exports.index = (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.json({
        data: contacts,
        message: "Contacts retrieved successfully",
        status: "success"
    });
};

// Handle create contact actions
exports.new = (req: any, res: any) => {

     // save the contact and check for errors
    contacts.push("Pyramids");

    res.json({
            data: contact,
            message: "New contact created!"
        });
};
```

**api-route.ts**

```
import contactController from "./contactController";
```

In the api-routes.ts, when I am trying to import the contactController module it is throwing the error

> Module has no default export

How can I import without the error? I have tried using "import {contactController} from "./contactController" but that did not work as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Documentation (see the "Export" and "Import" sections):* [Typescript Modules Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

### To complete Vasil's answer:

When you import a module this way:

```js
// <some_file>.ts
import <whatever_name_I_want> from "<path_to_my_awesome_module>";
```

`<my_awesome_module>.ts` needs to have a **default export**. For example, this can be done this way:

```js
// <my_awesome_module>.ts
export default foo = () => { // notice the 'default' keyword
  // ...
};

export bar = () => {
  // ...
};
```

With the code above, `<whatever_name_I_want>` will be the `foo` method (a module can only have **1** default export). In order to import the `bar` method as well, you will have to import it seperately:

```js
// <some_file>.ts
import <whatever_name_I_want>, { bar } from "<path_to_my_awesome_module>";
```

---

But according to what you're trying to do, there is probably no need to use a default export. You could simply export all your methods with the `export` keyword, like this:

```js
// contactController.ts
export index = (req: any, res: any) => { // no need for a default export
  // ...
};

export create = (req: any, res: any) => {
  // ...
};
```

and import them both either in brackets:

```js
// api-routes.ts
import { index, create } from "./contactController";

// Usage
index(...);
create(...);
```

or in a global variable:

```js
// api-routes.ts
import * as contactController from "./contactController";

// Usage
contactController.index(...);
contactController.create(...);
```

PS: I renamed your `new` method in `create` because "new" is already a JavaScript keyword.

Comment: accepted this answer as it has further explanation on top of Vasil's answer

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the way you export to:

```js
const contacts: String[] = [];

// Handle index actions
const index = (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.json({
        data: contacts,
        message: "Contacts retrieved successfully",
        status: "success"
    });
};

// Handle create contact actions
const newContact = (req: any, res: any) => {

     // save the contact and check for errors
    contacts.push("Pyramids");

    res.json({
            data: contact,
            message: "New contact created!"
        });
};

export default {index, newContact};
```

Then you should be able to import then like so

```js
import routes from './contactController';
```

Comment: Or also could do `import * as routes from './contactController'`