# error TS1192: Module '"http"' has no default export

Tags: angular

Info: node_modules/node-expose-sspi/dist/sso/client.d.ts:3:8 - error TS1192: Module '"http"' has no default export.
after I installed node-expose-sspi, then compiled the Angular project(version 10), I met this error. anyone give some advice for this? thanks~~

Code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { sso } from "node-expose-sspi";


@Injectable()
export class LanIPService {

    constructor() { }

    

    getLanID():any{
        
        (async () => {
            try {
              const response = await new sso.Client().fetch('http://localhost:3500');
              const json = await response.json();
              return json;
            } catch (e) {
              console.error(e);
            }
          })();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module '"http"' has no default export. While using typescript And Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66810369/module-http-has-no-default-export-while-using-typescript-and-node)

Comment: I would suggest asking in https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi/issues that you will more help form package maintainers for these type of errors

Comment: no, my question is that this error occurred in node_modules/node-expose-sspi/dist/sso/client.d.ts; so I can't find this reason at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is because webpack in angular doesn't include node librarys like http anymore. You have to provide them in the `angular.json` and `tsconfig.json` after installing them via npm. But even after you provided all necessary modules it will fail. This is because the library is for windows usage and not browser usage. Trying to use it in the browser will result in the library throwing an error, that it is not in a windows environment.