# Why i can't import "os" modules with "import" syntax?

Tags: node.js

With my node(v16.13.2)

```
const os = require("os");
```

this is perfectly work.

But

```
import os from "os";
```

This gives me an error that `Module 'os' has no default export`

I don't understand why it is.

And why node is designed like that.

Comment: Why? Because _"Module 'os' has no default export"_. Use `import * as os from "os"` to import the entire thing or only import what you need, eg `import { arch } from "os"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error TS1192: Module '" A.module"' has no default export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429927/error-ts1192-module-a-module-has-no-default-export)

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this by saving the file with **.mjs** extension instead of **.js**, or by adding
`{ "type": "module" }` to your package.json file

Comment: This would not fix the error OP is getting at all.